# Wrap all lines with character sequence in vim

Tags: linux, vim, regular-expression, gvim

So basically I copy/pasted some code, and I need to prepend and append some more code to each line. Each line is a function call, and is getting added to a switch statement as it's own case.

Right now it looks like:

```
switch(n)
{
    case 1: retVal = foo("bar"); break;
    case 2: retVal = foo("Bar"); break;
    foo("bAr");
    foo("BAr");
    foo("BAR");
}
```

And I need it to look like:

```
switch(n)
{
    case 1: retVal = foo("bar"); break;
    case 2: retVal = foo("Bar"); break;
    case 3: retVal = foo("bAr"); break;
    case 4: retVal = foo("BAr"); break;
    case 5: retVal = foo("BAR"); break;
}
```

The best I've come up with is:

```
:'<,'>s/I DONT KNOW/case SOMETHING: retVal = & break;/g
```

where `I DON'T KNOW` and `SOMETHING` need to be changed. The problem is I'm not comfortable enough with regex to know what to put there. Any ideas?

Edit: After seeing muru's answer I realized I should've posted [this](http://www.thegeekstuff.com/2009/04/vi-vim-editor-search-and-replace-examples/) link for the numbering part. Example 11 shows a way to renumber a sequence using regex, assuming you have an existing sequence.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming your visual-mode selection is limited to the lines with just `foo(...);`, the best that I can come up with is:

```
:let c=2|'<,'>g//let c=c+1|s/\v\S+/\="case ".c.": retVal = ".submatch(0)." break;"/
```

More readably:

```
let counter = 2
'<,'>g//                       " for some reason, we need both markers and g// for `let` to work
   let counter = counter + 1
   s/
     \v                        " `\v` is "very magic"
     \S+/                      " used for `\S` - all non-whitespace characters
          \=                   " Indicate that replacement is an expression
             "case " .         " `.` concatenates strings
             counter . 
             ": retVal = " . 
             submatch(0) . 
             " break;"
                            /
```

Adapted from [this Vim wikia post](http://vim.wikia.com/wiki/Using_an_expression_in_substitute_command).

Yes, I know. This is ugly. A better way exists.

---

Another way, using macros: (Start from the first line without the `case`)

```
qq
k:s/\v(case \d+: retVal = )(.*)\n(\s*)(.*)/\1\2\r\1\4 break;/|exe "norm \<c-a>"
j
q
```

Then use `@q` as many times as there are lines left.

Comment: I'm not sure if it helps, but I included a link I found relating to number sequences in my edit. The linked regex only renumbers an existing sequence, as opposed to extending one though.

Comment: @AdamWatson hmm, no the link didn't help much. But I arrived at a worse way!

Comment: Hahaha I like it! Unfortunately I couldn't get the first answer to work (running it changed nothing and it said "no matches found" or something) so I ended up using 2 commands (1 to prepend, the other append) and inserting the numbers myself as there weren't too many to do. I'll leave this open for a little longer though in the hopes someone will have a really ingenious & short answer.

Comment: @AdamWatson and in the future, do try out [vi.se], a sister site for Vim fans.